# ERC721 setApproveForAll for 2+ operators

Tags: solidity, erc-721

I was wondering how setApproveForAll is working. If the USER approves 2 operators(operatorA and operatorB), and operatorA create an auction and sells the USER's NFT first, is the job of operatorB to check if that NFT was already sold(and maybe if operatorB also runs an auction on that NFT, should close the auction)?
I hope my question makes sense.
Thank you.

Comment: hi @valentinrusinaru, please follow up you have an answer here

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

This validation step is perform by each marketplace at the time of sale execution.

So the sale should not go through if the token is transferred ("rugpulled", "fizzled") before the auction ends.

And in the user interface, the marketplace should come to know if the owner no longer owns the token so it can hide that offer.